# ¿Como proteger los archivos php y fotos subidos a mi host hostinger?

Tags: php, hosting

Hola a todos estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual he subido archivos a mi host los cuales les he puesto la extension .php asi como una carpeta de fotos, me gustaria proteger mis archivos tanto las fotos como los archivos php para que no sea vea ni su contenido ni su nombre, ya que al colocar por ejemplo www.mihost.com/uploads me muestra un indice, probe poniendo contraseña a la carpetas desde Cpanel el menu de mi host pero cuando uso el sistema aun si llamo las fotos desde el php o cualquier otro archivo me pide la clave, ayuda es una aplicacion web por cierto y requiero proteger las fotos de empleados y clientes.

Comment: crea un archivo index.php dentro de tu carpeta de fotos o sino manejalo con un archivo .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Si el sistema que usas para subir tus archivos no utiliza un sistema de usuarios que maneje privilegios lo único que se me ocurre (no es infalible) es poner en la carpeta uploads un archivo que se llame index.php y ahi redireccionar al indice de tu host. De esta forma cuando quieran ingresar a tudominio.com/uploads seran redirigidos a tudominio.com

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta busque los permisos y di con ellos me sale al darle click derecho a cada archivo o capeta, por ultimo pienso deshabilitar por completo todos los permisos en group y para others deshablitar todos los permisos, es necesario deshabilitar read para others? [![hostinger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBJgX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBJgX.png)